# Параметризация запроса

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Задача: взять кол-во монет из одной строки и прибавить это кол-во к другой строке, отняв соотвествено это кол-во у первого.Вот моя попытка реализовать:

```
id1= 530746886
id2 = 489569031
pay = 5
sql = """
UPDATE persons 
SET coins = coins + pay      
WHERE id =?
"""
cur.execute(sql, [(id1)])

sql = """
UPDATE persons 
SET coins = coins - pay      
WHERE id =?
"""

cur.execute(sql, [(id2)])
```

И всё мило, но проблема в строчке `SET coins = coins + pay` А именно он не видит переменную `pay`. Как же мне её внедрить в SQL запрос? И вообще как внедрять туда что-либо?

Comment: Так же, как внедрили id.

Comment: А можно с примером? Я просто не понимаю как присобачить второй параметр кроме id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
id1= 530746886
id2 = 489569031
pay = 5
sql = """
UPDATE persons 
SET coins = coins + ?
WHERE id = ?
"""


# первый UPDATE
params = (pay, id1)
cur.execute(sql, params)

# второй UPDATE
params = (-pay, id2)
cur.execute(sql, params)
```

Comment: Exception has occurred: TypeError
execute() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: @WestSide, поправил ответ...